# Is there a way to delay the setting of hyperref hypersetup values?

Tags: hyperref

I have a situation where the document title is set later, wrapped in another command (it has to do with language versions).

## Hypersetup load order

I would like to put the new title into the hypersetup `pdftitle` command.
The result is not desired. The file's metadata shows up in Adobe Reader as Baluga. It does not seem to matter whether I put the `\hypersetup` below my `specialmacro` or not.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\baluga{Baluga}
\newcommand\whale{}
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={\baluga{} \whale{}},%
}%
\newcommand\specialmacro{
    \renewcommand\whale{whale}
}
\begin{document}
\specialmacro{}

Test

\end{document}
```

---

## Update: Solution using Wrapper for `\hypersetup`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\baluga{Baluga}
\newcommand\whale{}
\newcommand\hyperset{
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={\baluga{} \whale{}},%
}%
}
\newcommand\specialmacro{
    \renewcommand\whale{whale}
    \hyperset
}
\begin{document}
\specialmacro{}

Test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the new edited version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\baluga{Baluga}
\newcommand\whale{}

\newcommand\hyperset{\hypersetup{pdftitle={\baluga{} \whale{}},}}

\begin{document}
 Test
\renewcommand\whale{whale}
\hyperset  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but that does not answer the question, "Is there a way to post-process setting the hyperref hypersetup values?" I appreciate the effort anyway.

Comment: perhaps \hypersetup command can be called just before the \end{document}. That would post-process the settings.

Comment: That is in interesting idea. I will try wrapping `\hypersetup`in a macro and calling it in the `\specialmacro` after the title is set.

Comment: It works. Here it is: `\newcommand\hyperset{\hypersetup{pdftitle={\baluga{} \whale{}},}}` and call it after the `\renewcommand\whale{whale}` in the `\specialmacro`. If you incorporate that into your answer I will give you credit for it.

Comment: You may also use `\AtEndDocument{\hypersetup{...}}` in the preamble so avoiding the need of typing it manually.